.Net Core with Apache Guacamole
I am new to this
I wanted to know how can i connect the apache Guacamole with my .net core
what am i trying to achieve is this below
I have the Apache  Guacamole setup on the Server i have the host, port, username, password.
I want to change the UI of the Apache Guacamole with Angular UI and Backend with .Net core Web API
I want to have a backend which connects with Apache Guacamole so I can modify the data and then show it on my own UI which is Angular.
any Suggestions? any git Rep? any code example of how to achieve that? would really be a help!
I did try finding the sharp github but it wasnm't much a help. I am not sure what I am trying to do is correct way or not!
I already have the server with apache running on it so i dont think so i need docker for that
all i want is to connect the backend(.net core web api) with Apache  Guacamole which i have and fetch some data and show it on my UI(Angular)
